# intellisense doesn't see that .dll has changed

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, intellisense

I added dll to my project(to a new folder'lib' in project directory) and I have used its features. Then the new version of the dll appeared, under the same name. I deleted library and reference from project, added the new one (with few extra methods). When I try to use these new methods, Intellisense calls it an error, and I cannot build my project. Without using new methods, everything works fine as if I was working with old version of dll.

I am using VS Express 2012 for Desktop.

Comment: Is the old DLL still in the GAC?

Comment: Maybe try doing a [clean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171480.aspx).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "dll appeared". Did it replace the old one? Does the old one still exist? If so, might as well check that you actually added the new dll --> right click ref --> Properties --> look at path and version.

Comment: In addition you could verify that "specificVersion" under these properties is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving, rebuilding, and restarting VS? It tends to get a little wonky with the intellisense, especially with user-defined classes, if it's been running too long.

It could also be something to do with namespaces if it got copied over from somewhere else? I've had this problem more than once with a class I wrote and use all over the place.